# jmeter parametrization for appending 0 to all values of csv file

Tags: jmeter

In have to parameterize csv file in my Jmeter scenario.

All values in csv start from zero like

```
0123456789
0234567899
0112312312
0423423433
0423423422
```

Since all values are as zero therefore csv is not supporting it which causes parametrization is not working.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

CSV Data Set config doesn't have any validation of input so values starting from zero should be fine.

The most common mistake for beginners is incorrect location of CSV Data Set Config in Test Plan. Try adding it **inside** [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) (or alternatively configure your [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) Loop Count parameter) and put [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) **as a child** if the request, you're trying to parametrize.